# Forgerock OpenAM

Tags: openam, forgerock

After completion of the installation, While logging in to Forgerock OpenAM, the screen is getting stuck at loading. How shall one rectify this problem for successful logging in into OpenAM.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y6mI.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You messed the cookie domain while installing, remember if you will access your am at http://server.domain.com, you should set your cookie domain either: server.domain.com, or domain.com